# How to import properties file within shared jar in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to create a shared project jar, that has some services. These service should make use of a properties file.

Ideally I just want to make use of the services lateron when I add the shared jar as a dependency to other projects. I don't want to make any further configuration like importing the shared property file or so.

Within the shared jar, I'd like to inject the properties using `Spring`. But how can I do this?

project-commons/src/main/java:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Value("${property.value}") private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

project-commons/src/main/resources/application.properties:

```
property.value=test
```

project-web/src/main/java:

```
@Component
public class SoapService {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    //should return "test"
    public String value() {
        return service.getValue();
    }
}
```

When I run it:

```
Illegal character in path at index 1: ${property.value}
```

So, the propertyfile is not resolved. But how can I tell spring to automatically use it when using the appropriate service?

Comment: Do you have a configuration to load the properties?

Comment: Here is a nice blog post about this: http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/#java

Comment: No, should I? I'd prefer to not having to configure anything when injecting this service in another project.

Comment: Yes, otherwise the module using the properties won't know that they're supposed to be loaded. Think about how application contexts work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Hank Lapidez, adding the following statement fixes the problem:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:appdefault.properties")
public CommonConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some variation of this:

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:my.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

in your application context xml file, or the equivalent in a java configurator (see `@PropertySource("classpath:my.properties")`). This should be repeated in any module that depends on the shared library's property file.