# spring-boot application.properties maven multi-module setup

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I'm struggling with application.properties setup in maven multimodule project. 
I have structure

```
--parent
----core-api
----infrastructure (infrastructure.properties)
----command
----web (application.properties)
```

I'm using different names for appliaction.properties, because I want to load them all in target module.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198688/merge-many-application-properties-files-instead-of-replace-on-spring-boot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867896/how-to-import-properties-file-within-shared-jar-in-spring) posts so I decided to put

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties","classpath:infrastructure.properties" })
```

to my **Application.class** in **web** module. But when I run command mvn spring-boot:run from my parent project I get exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.github.bilak.axonframework.poc.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [infrastructure.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180)
```

my project can be found [here](https://github.com/bilak/axonframework-poc)

1. How can I have this working while using maven plugin? Is there way to setup this in java and run with maven?
2. This is more related to maven, but can I run mvn spring-boot:run from web module without installing the dependent modules to local repository?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reuse Spring Boot infrastructure instead of doing your own thing. You could have `applications-infrastructure.properties` and enable the `infrastructure` profile.

Regarding your second question, no you should install the other modules first; you can also find a related discussion in [#3436](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3436)

Comment: That's true, that I can use properties as profile. But that doesn't work application-infrastructure.properties is not loaded I guess. I updated the project on github.

Comment: I ran your application and the infrastructure profile is loaded. So I don't know what your problem is. BTW you're not having a ServletInitializer in your web project so there's no chance you'll be able to deploy that war properly. Check https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: Problem is that h2 db should be created in folder ~/h2db/ and it's not there so I bet the application-infrastructure.properties is not loaded or it's loaded somehow incorrectly.

Comment: It's there for me (-rw-r--r--  1 snicoll  staff  208896 Aug 12 16:16 /Users/snicoll/h2db/axonpoc.mv.db). Anyway, there are better ways to figure out if the profile is loaded (the actuator for instance).

Comment: That's weird, it doesn't work for me - I don't see that db file, even if I try to change the server port in infrastructure.properties it doesn't change. Did you changed anything in my test project to work?

Comment: Ok so I've added actuator to the project and extended the ServletInitializer.  When I look at /env endpoint and find infrastructure, I can't find application-infrastructure.properties there. I can find them only when i put them to web module. On which OS are you running my app?

Comment: MacOS but I'd be very surprised if it had anything to do with the problem.

Comment: OK I'm on the same OS. So can you somehow help me how to resolve this issue? If I look into the localhost:8080/env I see there only application.properties but not infrastructure-application.properties

Comment: I did 1. git clone url 2. mvn clean install 3. cd web 4. mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: Ok this way it works. I will mark this thread as correct, but shouldn't it work even if I run mvn clean spring-boot run from parent project?